# How to use nested for() to get results intermittently and decreased?

Tags: php, for-loop

I want this **output:**

```
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   3   3   3
4   4   5   5   6   6
7   8   9   10  11  12
```

I think I need to three nested `For()`, But I don't know how should I print the above result. Here is my code, How to complete it? *(though I don't know, maybe my code is completely wrong)*

```
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)          // row
{
    for ($j=1; $j<=6; $j++)      // column
    {
        for($z=1; $z<=12; $z++)  // number
        {
            // what should be in here?
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** I want something like these examples: *(Although these examples are very simple, what I want is a little more harder)*

```
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
    for ($j=1; $j<=6; $j++)
    {
        echo $i.' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4   4
```

Or this: `echo $j;`

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

---

**Edit2:**
**Note:** I need to a code that be able to print this either: *(its logic is the same with first output)*

```
4   4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   6   6   6
7   7   8   8   9   9
10  11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: Can you actually explain the logic of each line, or of each column?

Comment: You better edit the question with some rference to *how are the values stored*. Is it a 2 dim array?

Comment: I think you've done something wrong, the section with the comment will execute 288 times.

Comment: @MarkBaker The logic: line1: Made up of one number (all number in line1 are the same), line2: Made up of two different number, ... , line6: Made up of six different number. Also all numbers all related to each other increasingly.

Comment: @Sajad Presumably this function should work with different parameters, eg starting number, or number of lines / columns (if not, you would just hardcode the values) so you need to explain how these rules are defined

Comment: `echo "1   1   1   1   1   1\n2   2   2   3   3   3\n4   4   5   5   6   6\n7   8   9   10  11  12";`

Comment: @Sajad if the values never change, then yes you certainly should just echo them.

Comment: @Steve no the output is not constant always, I added a new output.

Comment: are row and column always 4 and 6 respectively ? and the pattern is the same?

Comment: @Sajad please add what the table would look like if you were to add one extra row, or one extra column.  Please also explain what rules you use to decide what the table would look like.  There are an infinite number of algorithms that could be used to create a table like yours, so we need a little help narrowing it down.

Comment: @Andrew yes, always there is 4 rows and 6 columns.

Comment: @Sajad, how can you have 120 lines, AND always have 4 rows and 6 columns?

Comment: @JeffUK My bad. You are right, I removed that comment, I meant was I don't start with a constant number all the time. Sometime I start it with *120*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
var $c = 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
    var $noOfChanges = 6/$i;
    for ($j=1; $j<=6; $j++)
    {
        echo $c.' ';
        if($j%$noOfChanges==0){
            $c = $c + 1;
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Not tested.**

You can intialize the var `$c = 4;` to get the next pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working:

```
$length = 6;
$row = 0;
$number = 1;
$total = 0;
$n = $length;

while(true) {
 $n = floor($length/($row+1));
 for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
   echo $number;
   echo "\t";
 }
 $total+=$n;
 if($total >= $length) {
   $row++;
   $total = 0;
   echo "\n";
   if($n == 1 ) break;
 }

 $number++;

}
```